# How to create a class within a class in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a class based off an existing set of data. The columns include name, street address, city, state, and zip. I would like to create a class with name and address. Within this class I would like to have another class for address containing street address, city, state and zip.

My code looks like this for each private variable (I do not have variables for city, state or zip but I am sure I need them):

```
Private pCustomerName As String

Public Property Let CustomerName(Value As String)
  pCustomerName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get CustomerName() As String
    CustomerName = pCustomerName
End Property
```

What would we be different about the address section to include a sub-class I guess is what I'm asking.

Currently looks like this:

```
Public Property Let Address(Value As String) 
    pAddress = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = pAddress
End Property
```

Comment: someone please edit the code

Comment: You could edit your code: Highlight it and then hit ctrl+K

Comment: There is also the code icon in the edit window. Stack Overflow's way of pasting code is not very intuitive (in my opinion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right there man! You can simply create another class for your address data and instantiate it inside your Customer Class. You just need to use VBA's `Set` keyword to assign the Address object back and forth. It is also usually good practice to instantiate the Address object in the `Class_Initialize` and set it to `Nothing` in the `Class_Terminate` as shown below:

Customer Class:

```
Option Explicit
Private pCustomerName As String
Private pAddress As AddressObj

Public Property Let CustomerName(value As String)
  pCustomerName = value
End Property

Public Property Get CustomerName() As String
    CustomerName = pCustomerName
End Property

Public Property Set CustomerAddress(value As AddressObj)
    Set pAddress = value
End Property

Public Property Get CustomerAddress() As AddressObj
    Set CustomerAddress = pAddress
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pAddress = New AddressObj
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pAddress = Nothing
End Sub
```

Address Class (I called it AddressObj)

```
Option Explicit
Private pZipCode As Integer
Private pStreet As String
Private pState As String

Public Property Let ZipCode(value As Integer)
    pZipCode = value
End Property

Public Property Get ZipCode() As Integer
    ZipCode = pZipCode
End Property

Public Property Let Street(value As String)
    pStreet = value
End Property

Public Property Get Street() As String
    Street = pStreet
End Property

Public Property Let State(value As String)
    pState = value
End Property

Public Property Get State() As String
    State = pState
End Property

'... etc for other properties
```

Comment: Glad to help! :-)

Comment: Small anecdote, ZipCodes need not always be numeric. Otherwise nice answer, +1